# NextJS Websocket pattern problem (how to extract the stream from the websocket?)

Tags: next.js, websocket, trading, cryptocurrency

I'm making a crypto trading app with NextJS. It takes prices stream for all coins from the Bybit exchange API via WebSocket( WebSocket is a must because you can't get realtime updates with usual requests, also there's a rate limit for them ).

So, the problem is:
in nextJS you can use WebSocket only inside of the useEffect hook. And this hook must return WebSocket close method to close the WebSocket when refreshing/navigating to another page etc, to maintain it correctly, not to create new same WebSockets on refresh etc.

So, this WebSocket subscribes to all the coins and their prices and streams continuously, like many times a second. So, I cannot use the whole stream, because it would cause constant rerenders.
So I implemented the filtering logics inside the stream to update the state only for the current selectedCoin inside the app, and to update the state only when the price for this coins changes. So now it works perfectly well and the component rerenders only when the price changes. Great.

But...
It works great only with the single coin. And the app needs to support many coins simultaneously.. So.. for example when I change the coin inside the app, **it should be passed** to the websocket stream to start filtering its price. But, the websocket is already there and I cannot pass a new argument to it. So the only way is to close the current websocket and open a new one with the new coin or several if there's different coin opened positions orders etc.
But.. closing and opening a new websockets as I see, is not the best approach, because sometimes it just doesn't close for some reason or doesn't open... It's not stable and is "buggy"...
So the best way would be to open a single websocket and let it run forever, **extract somehow the stream from it**, and only after that filter the needed coins with the ability to change the argument for filtering.....

in short I need the app to support many coins simultaneously. For this I need to be able to filter realtime websocket stream without making a new websocket connection when I select a new coin or multiple coins are active inside the app...
I hope I explained it well...

and so I wonder how to implement it... is Redux would help? at the first glance it won't. Is nextJS 13 app folder would help? idk seems not. The only way which seems to be possible, it to put this websocket on the server side, and then make another websocket to connect the server and the client and pass the stream to the client.. but again is it even possible idk, will I be able to stream the first coin prices stream through another websocket? idk. Or maybe there's a much more simpler implementation?

so here's the code finally:)
here's the useEffect for the websocket

```
useEffect(() => {
        const getPrices = async (ws: WebSocket, setter, selectedCoin: string, coinsHistory: string[]) => {
            await trader.getPrices(ws, setter, selectedCoin, coinsHistory);
        };

        const pricesWS = new WebSocket(trader.pricesUrl);
        getPrices(pricesWS, setPrice, selectedCoin, coinsHistory);

        return () => {
            if (pricesWS.readyState === 1) pricesWS.close();
        };
    }, [coinsHistory]);
```

But as I mentioned it's not ideal at all because very often it fails to close or to open. Also a new websocket will only update price if there will be an update for this coin, so **there can be and will be a big lag for many coins in getting the price and it's unacceptable for a trading app**

and here's the method to filter out the needed coin, but as I mentioned it works only with the single pre-passed coin, **so there's no big sense in reading the code. The stream from the websocket should somehow be extracting constantly to another place and there should be similar logic to filter out active coins**

```
getPrices = async (ws: WebSocket, setter: any, selectedCoin: string, coinsHistory: string[]): Promise<any> => {
    const res = await axios.get(`https://api-testnet.bybit.com/v5/market/instruments-info?category=linear`);

    ws.onopen = () => {
        console.log('prices webSocket opened');

        const pingInterval = setInterval(() => {
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({ op: 'ping' }));
        }, 30000);

        ws.send(JSON.stringify({ op: 'ping' }));

        ws.onerror = () => {
            clearInterval(pingInterval);
            console.log('ERROR!!!!');
        };
        ws.onclose = () => {
            clearInterval(pingInterval);
            console.log('prices WS closed!');
        };

        const coins = res.data.result.list;

        for (let coin of coins) {
            ws.send(
                JSON.stringify({
                    op: 'subscribe',
                    args: [`tickers.${coin.symbol}`],
                })
            );
        }

        let symbols = [];

        ws.onmessage = e => {
            let res = JSON.parse(e.data.toString('utf8'));

            if (res.data?.symbol && /USDT/i.test(res.data?.symbol)) {
                let stream = res.data;

                if (stream.lastPrice) {
                    //take streams only with the last price
                    if (!symbols.some(arr => arr.value === stream.symbol)) {
                        symbols.push({ value: stream.symbol, label: stream.symbol, price: stream.lastPrice });
                    }
                }
                let newData = symbols.slice(0);
                //update price
                newData.forEach(coin => {
                    //only for coinHistory coins
                    if (coinsHistory.includes(coin.value)) {
                        if (stream.symbol === coin.value && stream.lastPrice && coin.price !== stream.lastPrice) {
                            let tempArray = [];
                            coin.price = stream.lastPrice;
                            console.log('price update');
                            tempArray.push({ price: stream.lastPrice, label: stream.symbol });
                            setter(tempArray);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    };
};
```

So I hope my question is clear. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got two suggestions, use the experimental appDir client components for all the pages where ya would need access to the websocket stream and use socketio for the socket connection.

Main reason for using the new client components in your case would be because these client components sort of act like their own islands. Meaning they would only get re-rendered themselves instead of the whole app when the content values change.

Comment: hey, thanks a lot. But frankly as I see in the react dev extension and in the console logs, it's already rerendering just a single component with the logics.

Comment: and what do I need the socketIO for? thank you

Comment: oh I guess you mean just to be able to use websocket on the server side...

Comment: but... I need real time constant updates for the client.. I think just putting a ws onto the server side won't make a continuous connection to the client?

Comment: @Eugene1111 you can use socketio on the client side as well. I'm mainly suggesting the use of socket io over axios due to my previous experience with axios. 
https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api

Comment: uou can't use server side modules in the client and axios is not for ws connections

Comment: one: socketio isn't strictly a server side module.
two: you could use axios, fetch etc. for websockets but its not recommended.
three: I was mainly pointing out your use of axios bc of my previous answer. (bad experience with axios, would rather use fetch instead of axios)

Comment: ok thank you I just realized that there is a client side module. will try that right now and say did it work or not. thank you:)

Comment: no problem! Good luck and have fun with your project man. :D

Comment: ok it just gets the CORS error and that's it

Comment: did you set the origin of the request?

Comment: if it still spits out CORS errors after maybe check the socketIO docs (https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/) and this guide (https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-websocket-communication-next-js)